# Firefox Click to Play Exceptions

Tags: firefox

In Firefox, there's the setting click_to_play in the about:config that makes it so you have to click on flash applications to make them play. But some applications don't play nice with this and it breaks last.fm and grooveshark.

So is there any way to add site exceptions for this click_to_play setting to not apply to.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open a new tab and go to `about:permissions`.
2. Search for the sites you want to configure the click to play settings for.
3. Select the site in question and change the Plugins dropdown option to "Allow".

---

Alternatively, load up the site in question, click on the plugin button in the address bar, click on the down arrow and select the "Always activate plugins for this site" option.

[image: Activate plugins via address bar.]

Comment: What version of firefox is this for? I'm running version 16, and I don't see either of these options. My about:permissions doesn't have a plugins dropdown and no button on address bar.

Comment: I checked version 16.0.2 and both options are on there. The plugins button will only appear on the address bar if the web page requires you to enable plugins (go to the web page that requires the Flash plugin and check again).

Comment: I guess this is a bug. I have this problem in the version 21 as well as I had in 20. The exceptions doesn’t work in about:permissions. But the plugin button works. @user19192 It’s on the “website address bar”, not about:permissions address bar. So first open the website.

Comment: Is there something similar to the `about:permissions` steps for Firefox 30's blocking of all plugins?

Comment: About:permissions was [removed for FF45](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=933917) and [some of](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2994059) the functionality was moved into a dialog accessible from right-clicking on a page, View Page Info, Permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/) plugin in Firefox you can do this. It has a on option to whitelist sites.

You can find it via [tools] [Addons] (or <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>). Then extentions, flashblock, options, tab whitelist.